# How to find duplicate values based upon first 10 digits?

Tags: java, collections

I have a scenario where i have a list as below  :

```
List<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>();  
a1.add("1070045028000");
a1.add("1070045028001");
a1.add("1070045052000");
a1.add("1070045086000");
a1.add("1070045052001");
a1.add("1070045089000");
```

I tried below to find duplicate elements but it will check whole string instead of partial string(first 10 digits).

```
for (String s:al){
         if(!unique.add(s)){  
             System.out.println(s);
         }
     }
```

Is there any possible way to identify all duplicates based upon the first 10 digits of a number  & then  find the lowest strings by comparing from the duplicates & add in to another list?

Note: Also there will be only 2 duplicates with each 10 digit string code always!!

Comment: You can use .substring(0,10) to get the first ten digits for comparison. Could you clarify what you mean by the lowest strings? Are they strings below a certain threshold number or below a threshold within the values of the duplicates?

Comment: Where is the part where you do any work on the first 10 digits?

Comment: @PoliticRevolutionnaire  i mean the code with lowest number while doing the comparision

Comment: @RajRaichand to compare any two numbers is simple, you can just use the .compareTo method between strings or you can read them as ints and compare that way. Are you looking to take all the numbers which share the first 10 digits and then only adding the smallest among them to the other list?

Comment: @PoliticRevolutionnaire  Let me clear this....first i want to find the duplicate strings by using only first 10 digits....after getting duplicates i want to compare complete string value 13 digits and find lowest string code based upon the comparision  and add that string code in another list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight-forward loop solution would be

```
List<String> a1 = Arrays.asList("1070045028000", "1070045028001",
    "1070045052000", "1070045086000", "1070045052001", "1070045089000");

Set<String> unique = new HashSet<>();
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

for(String s: a1) {
    String firstTen = s.substring(0, 10);
    if(!unique.add(firstTen)) map.put(firstTen, s);
}
for(String s1: a1) {
    String firstTen = s1.substring(0, 10);
    map.computeIfPresent(firstTen, (k, s2) -> s1.compareTo(s2) < 0? s1: s2);
}
List<String> minDup = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

First, we add all duplicates to a `Map`, then we iterate over the list again and select the minimum for all values present in the map.

Alternatively, we may add all elements to a map, collecting them into lists, then select the minimum out of those, which have a size bigger than one:

```
List<String> minDup = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

for(String s: a1) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(s.substring(0, 10), x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(s);
}
for(List<String> list: map.values()) {
    if(list.size() > 1) minDup.add(Collections.min(list));
}
```

This logic is directly expressible with the Stream API:

```
List<String> minDup = a1.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.substring(0, 10)))
    .values().stream()
    .filter(list -> list.size() > 1)
    .map(Collections::min)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Since you said that there will be only 2 duplicates per key, the overhead of collecting a `List` before selecting the minimum is negligible.

---

The solutions above assume that you only want to keep values having duplicates. Otherwise, you can use

```
List<String> minDup = a1.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toMap(s -> s.substring(0, 10), Function.identity(),
            BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.<String>naturalOrder())),
        m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())));
```

which is equivalent to

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
for(String s: a1) {
    map.merge(s.substring(0, 10), s, BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
}
List<String> minDup = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Common to those solutions is that you don’t have to identify duplicates first, as when you want to keep unique values too, the task reduces to selecting the minimum when encountering a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

You may group by a `(String s) -> s.substring(0, 10)`

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.substring(0, 10)));
```

`map.values()` would give you `Collection<List<String>>` where each `List<String>` is a list of duplicates.

```
{
1070045028=[1070045028000, 1070045028001], 
1070045089=[1070045089000], 
1070045086=[1070045086000], 
1070045052=[1070045052000, 1070045052001]
}
```

If it's a single-element list, no duplicates were found, and you can filter these entries out.

```
{
1070045028=[1070045028000, 1070045028001], 
1070045052=[1070045052000, 1070045052001]
}
```

Then the problem boils down to reducing a list of values to a single value.

```
[1070045028000, 1070045028001] -> 1070045028000
```

We know that the first 10 symbols are the same, we may ignore them while comparing.

```
[1070045028000, 1070045028001] -> [000, 001]
```

They are still raw `String` values, we may convert them to numbers.

```
[000, 001] -> [0, 1]
```

A natural `Comparator<Integer>` will give `0` as the minimum.

```
0
0 -> 000 -> 1070045028000
```

Repeat it for all the lists in `map.values()` and you are done.

The code would be

```
List<String> result = map
    .values()
    .stream()
    .filter(list -> list.size() > 1)
    .map(l -> l.stream().min(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> Integer.valueOf(s.substring(10)))).get())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

While I hate doing your homework for you, this was fun. :/

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> al=new ArrayList<>();
    al.add("1070045028000");
    al.add("1070045028001");
    al.add("1070045052000");
    al.add("1070045086000");
    al.add("1070045052001");
    al.add("1070045089000");

    List<String> ret=new ArrayList<>();
    for(String a:al) {
        boolean handled = false;
        for(int i=0;i<ret.size();i++){
            String ri = ret.get(i);
            if(ri.substring(0, 10).equals(a.substring(0,10))) {
                Long iri = Long.parseLong(ri);
                Long ia = Long.parseLong(a);
                if(ia < iri){
                    //a is smaller, so replace it in the list
                    ret.set(i, a);
                }
                //it was a duplicate, we are done with it
                handled = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!handled) {
            //wasn't a duplicate, just add it
            ret.add(a);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(ret);
}
```

prints

```
[1070045028000, 1070045052000, 1070045086000, 1070045089000]
```

Comment: Why not use String.compareTo(String) instead of parsing to Long?

Comment: But `[1070045028000, 1070045052000, 1070045086000, 1070045089000]` isn’t the correct answer, as neither `1070045086000` nor `1070045089000` have duplicates.

Comment: Because these are numbers. Imagine comparing `012345678901` and `0123456789001`. The String comparison will find the second to be smaller (0<1 at index 11), which it is not.

Comment: @Holger was it a requirement to only add the duplicates? The question is unclear

Comment: @f1sh Makes sense, thanks for explanation.  Also I assume the question wanted the ones that did not have duplicates as well just like you did.  It is not very clear.

Comment: Ok, it’s not that clear, but otherwise, it would be a rather trivial task. By the way, since we force the strings to have exactly ten digits, string comparison is sufficient, even with leading zeros; your counter-example incorporates strings with different length, which can’t happen as a result of `substring(0, 10)`.

Comment: @Holger yes, that can happen. we only use the first 10 characters for the "uniqueness" check, but the number behind it (which is what we compare only when a 10-char-duplicate is found) might have a different length.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it – construct a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and store just the 10-digit prefix:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
for (String number : a1) {
    String prefix = number.substring(0, 10);
    if (set.contains(prefix)) {
        System.out.println("found duplicate prefix [" + prefix + "], skipping " + number);
    } else {
        set.add(prefix);
    }
}
```